# How to upload the file folder or find a way to replace it

Tags: javascript, file-upload, directory

I am working on my web homework recently. I meet a problem that the pictures from client should be uploaded to server. I found many javascript plugins to upload pictures, but I wonder if I can upload a folder which contains many pictures directly instead of just select a lot of pictures, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write the input tag like this

```
<input type="file" name="blabla" directory webkitdirectory multiple/>
```

**Note:** This only supported by Google Chrome 13+, Firefox 50+, and Microsoft Edge

**Resource:** [HTMLInputElement.webkitdirectory](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/webkitdirectory)